# Migratory aptitude of chlorobenzene vs nitrobenzene in pinacol-pinacolone

Tags: organic-chemistry, rearrangements

I do know the basic order of migratory aptitude in pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement, which is usually said as subject to reaction conditions.

However, I wanted to know how can I compare the migratory aptitude of chlorobenzene vs nitrobenzene in pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement? What are the factors that we are supposed to check when only the benzene substituent is changed?

Comment: Higher the electron density in the benzene ring higher the migratory aptitude. So, the chloro derivative will have a higher migratory aptitude than the nitro derivative.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar thanks, I heard about this some time ago aswell however is there any rationale behind this logic?

Comment: @Ashish I guess you can think about this in terms of the transition state, where there is partial positive charge on both the carbon that the group is migrating from, and the carbon it's migrating to. If there is more electron density on the migrating group, it can donate some of that density to the positive carbons and make the TS more stable. (this is my guess)